# Selecting a child with Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

Is this part of the code right?

```
result2.find_element_by_xpath("./a[3]").click()
```

I want to get the third 'a' component from a 'div'

I am experiencing this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./a[3]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

This is part of the code that includes the segment:

```
logear = browser.find_element_by_id('gs_hdr_tsi')
logear.click()
logear.send_keys('Connexins and pannexins in Alzheimer’s disease')
logear.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(0.3)
result2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('gs_fl')
result2.find_element_by_xpath("./a[3]").click() '''This line gives the error'''
```

Comment: Try `time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try to add more time `time.sleep(3)` or wait for the element.*

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "./a[3]")))
element.click()
```

---

Per Comment

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_browser.get("https://scholar.google.com/")

Search_input = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser, 30).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gs_hdr_tsi")))

Search_input.send_keys("Connexins and pannexins in Alzheimer’s disease" + Keys.RETURN)

try:
    chrome_browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    cited_by_link = chrome_browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Cited by")
    cited_by_link.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: It is still not working, time maybe is not the problem

Comment: @JoaquinI my answer is for the error, can you share the  link? what browser are you running? and what is not working

Comment: Link: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Connexins+and+pannexins+in+Alzheimer%E2%80%99s+disease&btnG=   Browser: Google Chrome and the problem is that it doesnt go to the link in button with text "Cited By" or "Citado por" in spanish

Comment: No, but I have tried with R code with the scholar library and in that way it works, thank you very much. What should I do now? Close the question as answered or cancel the question?